# Are Windows Phone 8.1 GDR 2, Windows Phone 8.1 Update 2 and Windows Phone 8.1 Denim update same?

Tags: 8.1, lumia-denim-update, gdr-2

As the question says, are the following the one and the same?

- Windows Phone 8.1 GDR 2
- Windows Phone 8.1 Update 2
- Windows Phone 8.1 Denim

My Lumia 1320 currently has a firmware version of 3058.50000.1424.0002 and OS Version as 8.10.12393.890.

According to this page, the firmware version for Denim in India is the same as mine, but the OS version is 8.10.14234.375. I'm confused by all this. Can someone clarify?

Comment: Denim is 8.1 Update 1 - not sure what colour codename will be for Lumia phones for 8.1 Update 2

Comment: @RowlandShaw Are you sure that Denim is 8.1 Update 1? I think not. Is there any post or Microsoft document mentioning it?

Comment: From: http://lumiaconversations.microsoft.com/2015/01/15/lumia-denim-update-coming-way/ "The Lumia Denim update gives you new, innovative, premium features for work and play, combining the latest from Windows Phone 8.1 Update 1 with exclusive Lumia innovations."

Comment: @RowlandShaw Oh great! Thanks a ton for the clarification.So Lumia Denim is an independent moniker and has nothing to do with Windows Phone 8.1 Update 2!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Denim is 8.1 Update 1](http://lumiaconversations.microsoft.com/2015/01/15/lumia-denim-update-coming-way/), Windows Phone 8.1 Update 2 (GDR2) doesn't appear to have been officially announced yet.

For an Indian Lumia 1320, the [current update level is Denim](http://www.microsoft.com/en/mobile/support/software-update/wp8-software-update/wp8-availability-in-asia-pacific/), with an OS version of 8.10.14234.375. If you got your phone via a different market, then the released version may differ (such as an import from China, which is still on Cyan)

You can confirm if you've got Cyan or Denim by going to **settings** > **extras+info**, and at the top you will see whether the phone thinks it is Lumia Denim or Lumia Cyan.

You can of course also force a check for updates by going to **settings** > **phone update** and press <kbd>check for updates</kbd> (There will also be the option for when scheduled updates should happen if you're on 8.1 Update 1 or later)